# Clip a rectangle by the size of another (small) rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, path-clipping, clip

I'm trying to make a hole in the 2nd rectangle by the dimension of the 3rd rectangle. It seems that `\clip`, as it specified in the manual, is clipping all the subsequent drawings. Is there an `invert clip` command? I'm new to `tikz`.

Basically, I want the 3rd rectangle to have a white background by removing a portion from the 2nd rectangle. Currently, I used  `\path[fill=white]` to solve the problem.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes,decorations,decorations.text, mindmap,shadings,patterns,matrix,arrows.meta,intersections,automata,backgrounds,patterns.meta}


\begin{document}
%\begin{figure}[H]
%\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  coord/.style = {help lines, color=gray!40, dashed,xstep=0.2cm,ystep=0.2cm},%
  2ndRect/.style = {magenta, pattern=crosshatch, pattern color=magenta},%
  3rdRect/.style = {magenta, pattern=crosshatch dots, pattern color=blue},%
  insideArrow/.style = {black,{latex[scale=2]}-{latex[scale=2]}},%
  simpleArrow/.style = {black,{-latex}},%
  every node/.append style = {font =\bfseries\footnotesize},%
  % scale=.75,
  transform shape
  ]
  %
  % Draw HelpLines just to work faster
  %
   \draw[coord] (-2,-2) grid (20,10);
   \draw[<->,ultra thin] (0,0)--(20,0) node[right]{$x$};
   \draw[<->,ultra thin] (0,0)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};.
   \foreach \x in {0,0.5,...,19}
     \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
   \foreach \y in {0,0.5,...,3}
     \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};

  %
  % Draw Rectangles
  %
  \draw (2,0.2) rectangle (18,2.4);                       % 1st rectangle
  \draw[2ndRect] (4.5,0.4) rectangle (15.5,2.2);          % 2nd rectangle
  \path[fill=white](6.5,0.6) rectangle (13.5,2);          % workaround 4 clipping background
  \draw[3rdRect] (6.5,0.6) rectangle (13.5,2);            % 3rd rectangle
  %\clip (6.5,0.6) rectangle (13.5,2);          % clipping background
  \node [draw, fill=white] at (7.8,1.3) {S/R1};                              % label
  \node [draw, fill=white]  at (12.3,1.3) {S/R1};                             % label
  \draw[insideArrow] (8.5,1.3) -- (11.6,1.3);             % arrow btwen small rectangles
  \node at (1,1.3) {S4};        % label
  \draw[simpleArrow] (1.4,1.3) -- (2.8,1.3);             % arrow
  \node at (3.25,1.3) {S3};     % label
  \draw[simpleArrow] (3.6,1.3) -- (5.2,1.3);             % arrow
  \node at (5.5,1.3) {S2};      % label
  \draw[simpleArrow] (5.8,1.3) -- (6.4,1.3);             % arrow
  \node at (19,1.3) {R4};       % label
  \draw[simpleArrow] (13.6,1.3) -- (14.2,1.3);           % arrow
  \node at (16.75,1.3) {R3};    % label
  \draw[simpleArrow] (15,1.3) -- (16.4,1.3);             % arrow
  \node at (14.5,1.3) {R2};     % label
  \draw[simpleArrow] (17.2,1.3) -- (18.6,1.3);           % arrow
   
\end{tikzpicture}
%\label{fig:tikz}
%\caption{diagrama}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `even odd rule` to make holes. See section 15.5.2 in [pgfmanual](https://texdoc.org/serve/pgfmanual/0#page=181)

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes,decorations,decorations.text, mindmap,shadings,patterns,matrix,arrows.meta,intersections,automata,backgrounds,patterns.meta}


\begin{document}
%\begin{figure}[H]
%\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  coord/.style = {help lines, color=gray!40, dashed,xstep=0.2cm,ystep=0.2cm},%
  2ndRect/.style = {magenta, pattern=crosshatch, pattern color=magenta},%
  3rdRect/.style = {magenta, pattern=crosshatch dots, pattern color=blue},%
  insideArrow/.style = {black,{latex[scale=2]}-{latex[scale=2]}},%
  simpleArrow/.style = {black,{-latex}},%
  every node/.append style = {font =\bfseries\footnotesize},%
  % scale=.75,
  transform shape
  ]
  %
  % Draw HelpLines just to work faster
  %
   \draw[coord] (-2,-2) grid (20,10);
   \draw[<->,ultra thin] (0,0)--(20,0) node[right]{$x$};
   \draw[<->,ultra thin] (0,0)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};.
   \foreach \x in {0,0.5,...,19}
     \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
   \foreach \y in {0,0.5,...,3}
     \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};

  %
  % Draw Rectangles
  %
  \draw (2,0.2) rectangle (18,2.4);                       % 1st rectangle
  \draw[2ndRect, even odd rule] (4.5,0.4) rectangle (15.5,2.2) (6.5,0.6) rectangle (13.5,2);          % 2nd rectangle
%  \path[fill=white](6.5,0.6) rectangle (13.5,2);          % workaround 4 clipping background
  \draw[3rdRect, even odd rule] (6.5,0.6) rectangle (13.5,2) (7.3,1.05) rectangle node[midway, black]{S/R1} (8.3,1.55) (11.8,1.05) rectangle node[midway, black]{S/R1} (12.8,1.55);            % 3rd rectangle
  %\clip (6.5,0.6) rectangle (13.5,2);          % clipping background
%  \node [draw, opacity=0.5] at (7.8,1.3) {S/R1};                              % label
%  \node [draw, opacity=.5]  at (12.3,1.3) {S/R1};                             % label
  \draw[insideArrow] (8.5,1.3) -- (11.6,1.3);             % arrow btwen small rectangles
  \node at (1,1.3) {S4};        % label
  \draw[simpleArrow] (1.4,1.3) -- (2.8,1.3);             % arrow
  \node at (3.25,1.3) {S3};     % label
  \draw[simpleArrow] (3.6,1.3) -- (5.2,1.3);             % arrow
  \node at (5.5,1.3) {S2};      % label
  \draw[simpleArrow] (5.8,1.3) -- (6.4,1.3);             % arrow
  \node at (19,1.3) {R4};       % label
  \draw[simpleArrow] (13.6,1.3) -- (14.2,1.3);           % arrow
  \node at (16.75,1.3) {R3};    % label
  \draw[simpleArrow] (15,1.3) -- (16.4,1.3);             % arrow
  \node at (14.5,1.3) {R2};     % label
  \draw[simpleArrow] (17.2,1.3) -- (18.6,1.3);           % arrow
   
\end{tikzpicture}
%\label{fig:tikz}
%\caption{diagrama}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]